# How do I get Karma?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how to earn karma on this site.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9061/how-do-i-get-karma?/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are the best ways to get karma:

- +10 for your answer or question being upvoted
- +15 for your answer being selected
- +2  for accepting an answer to your question

So ask questions, and answer others.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 33

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-09**:
nice posting. I can't psot because I don't have enough karma

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-16**:
can u give me more points?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-16**:
@Gazer You can always ask questions and answer questions. Until you've gained a few points there are spam prevention measures in place with respect to links etc.

**Comment by [herodotus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5890/herodotus/) on 2013-11-12**:
oh,good question.I wanna get more karma too.And thanks for tfoote's answer.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-13**:
@Gazer No, you have to earn them as described in this answer.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
how reduce karma?

**Comment by [JJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/18839/jj/) on 2014-06-11**:
Q: How many points do you need to be able to post a question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-02**:\

> How many points do you need to be able to post a question?

0. 

But new posts by new users will be held for moderation, and will not show up until a moderator approves them (this is an important anti-spam measure).

**Comment by [dymoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/88887/dymoon/) on 2021-11-04**:
I get Karma for answer?